# How send command(text, digit, byte or another) from android(or computer) to esp8266 arduino module?

Tags: android, arduino, esp8266

I have `arduino esp8266 module (NodeMTU)` and I want send some data(string, int, bytes or another - I do not know what can be)  to this module from my android. I want create Remote Control of my android.

For example I press buttnon `ONN` on my android device and on the my esp8266 module LED lights connected t it. But I not understend how do it. I tried different simples in `Arduino IDE` but I not found it. I fount how get `html`

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h> 
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>

/* Set these to your desired credentials. */
const char *ssid = "ESPap";
const char *password = "thereisnospoon";

ESP8266WebServer server(80);

/* Just a little test message.  Go to http://192.168.4.1 in a web browser
 * connected to this access point to see it.
 */
void handleRoot() {
    server.send(200, "text/html", "<h1>You are connected</h1>");
}

void setup() {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("Configuring access point...");
    /* You can remove the password parameter if you want the AP to be open. */
    WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);

    IPAddress myIP = WiFi.softAPIP();
    Serial.print("AP IP address: ");
    Serial.println(myIP);
    server.on("/", handleRoot);
    server.begin();
    Serial.println("HTTP server started");
}

void loop() {
    server.handleClient();
}
```

but I need send command(int, strin or another)-> make somethin on the `esp8266`

Answer (score -1):

You can use the WiFiWebServer example. It can be found in the Arduino IDE at Data -> Examples -> ESP8266WiFi -> WiFiWebServer. [Or here.](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/ESP8266WiFi/examples/WiFiWebServer/WiFiWebServer.ino)

You can then send data to your ESP by sending a http request. Test it by typing    http://your-esp-ip-adress/gpio/1   into your browser. "/gpio/1" is the transmitted data.

Now there are a lot of possible solutions to build a remote control on your Android.

1. Find an App that can send http requests.
2. Create widgets on your Android with your web-browser that link to your request.
3. Build a web page with links to your request and host it on a local server.
4. Use the ESP itself to host a simple web page.
5. Program an App.